# Cannot upload notebook to jovian

Tags: error-handling, google-colaboratory, http-status-code-400

I trying to use jovian platform and google colab to run jupyter notebook. When I am trying to upload the notebook to my jovian account, I see this error.

Colab commit failed: (HTTP 400) Unauthorized access to tahmid1989/01-pytorch-basics

I am giving correct API key when it is prompted.
I am using same google account for my google colab and jovian.
Still it is not working.

Here is what I am trying.

```
!pip install jovian --upgrade --quiet
import jovian
jovian.commit(project='01-pytorch-basics')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening Colab from Jovian? It would be better to open the notebook on Colab via Jovian.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB8JP.png)

I can only commit my notebook from Colab to Jovian when I open it via Jovian.

Alternatively, you can try to run the Jupyter locally or run on Binder, then will be able to commit to Jovian..

Answer (score 0):

- logout and login once from jovian.ai
- restart kernel on Colab
- run jovian.commit as usual
  I understand why it’s happening, will fix. But for now logout/login should work for you.